# free-electrons error with apache2

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, python

I want to install the free-electrons(https://github.com/free-electrons/elixir) on Bash on Windows to search Linux kernel source code, I follow the github steps to do it. But Apache2 run error(Internal Server Error), I found a lot of information, but still can not solve, please help me, thank your!

steps as follows(Bash on Windows, Windows version 14393)

1. `cd /usr/local & git clone https://github.com/free-electrons/elixir`
2. config env `LXR_REPO_DIR & LXR_DATA_DIR`
3. install apache2 `# apt-get install apache2`
4. run command `./script.sh list-tags` & `./update.py` in elixir dir
5. config apache2 as follow

in **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
<Directory /usr/local/elixir/http/>
    Options +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    SetEnv PYTHONIOENCODING utf-8
    SetEnv LXR_PROJ_DIR /srv/elixir-data
</Directory>
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

in **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/elixir/http
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule "^/$" "/linux/latest/source" [R]
    RewriteRule "^/.*/(source|ident|search)" "/web.py" [PT]
</VirtualHost>
```

I use `a2enmod` command to insmod some mod, and then, I start apache2

`# service apache2 start`

I use the chrome to access `127.0.0.1`, the apache2 show message

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80
```

in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
[Wed Jun 14 09:12:55.380730 2017] [http:error] [pid 161:tid 139685623957248] [client 127.0.0.1:3486] AH02429: Response header name '<!--' contains invalid characters, aborting request
[Wed Jun 14 09:12:55.380730 2017] [cgid:error] [pid 161:tid 139685623957248] (-102)Unknown error -102: [client 127.0.0.1:3486] AH02550: Failed to flush CGI output to client
```

My python3 version was 3.5.2, apache2 version was 2.4.7

How should I solve this problem, please help me, thank your!

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever get this working? I went through the same issue and eventually discovered that errors produced by web.py were formatted incorrectly for HTML so it wasn't possible to see them in the web browser. I also discovered that if you set the correct environment variables, you can run web.py directly which will allow you to see the errors.

Here is what I did:

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
LXR_PROJ_DIR=/srv/elixir-data
SCRIPT_URL=/linux/latest/source
export SCRIPT_URL LXR_PROJ_DIR PYTHONIOENCODING
./web.py
```

Keep in mind that LXR_PROJ_DIR needs to contain your project repository and data. For example, if your project is "linux" (as it appears to be from above), you should have the following directories:

```
LXR_REPO_DIR=/srv/elixir-data/linux/repo # this is where your git repository should be
LXR_DATA_DIR=/srv/elixir-data/linux/data # this is where update.py put the .db files
```

Hopefully this helps!